# Simplifying $3x^2(x+8)^3+3x^3(x+8)^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

I found the derivative of $[x^3(x+8)^3]$ to equal $3x^2(x+8)^3+3x^3(x+8)^2$ using Chain Rule.

Somehow it can simplify further to: $6x^2(x+4)(x+8)^2$.

I can't manage the steps to get it to the simplified form.

Comment: Note that $3x^2y^3+3x^3y^2=3x^2y^2(y+x)$ and in this case $y=x+8$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carry out continuous factorizations, as :

$$3x^2(x+8)^3+3x^3(x+8)^2 = 3x^2\Big[(x+8)^3+x(x+8)^2\Big] $$
$$=$$
$$3x^2(x+8)^2\Big[x+8 + x\Big] = 3x^2(x+8)^2(2x+8) $$
$$=$$
$$\boxed{6x^2(x+4)(x+8)^2}$$

Comment: Know anywhere I could read up on this??

Comment: @pijoborde What do you mean ? You just factor out equal terms.

Comment: Would you be willing to edit in the steps with words as you factored them out? I am not seeing it at this time.

Comment: Well, first of all we see that we have $3x^2$ and $3x^3= 3x^2 \cdot x$. So we factor out $3x^2$ and the rest remain the same. Then we have $(x+8)^2$ and $(x+8)^3 = (x+8)^2 \cdot (x+8)$ and thus we factor out $(x+8)^2$. Then, we carry out the operations left in the parentheses and factor out $2$, since $2x+8 = 2(x+4)$.

Comment: thank you so much. That helped a lot being able to read along. Thank you.

Comment: @pijoborde Glad I could help ! If you consider that this gave a complete answer to your question, you may mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking on the tick marker below the vote buttons.

Comment: Done! Thanks again!